# Educative questions with an Example from Operator theory (non-closable operators)

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-algebras

I am teaching myself Operator Theory, and I found this question in a book I am reading.

We have these facts:

$\bullet$ Every normed linear vectorial space admits a completion to be a Banach space.

$\bullet$ A linear operator $A: D(A) \subset X \rightarrow X$ on a Banach Space $X$ is closed iff $(D(A), \|\cdot \|_G)$ is a Banach sapce while $(\|\cdot\|_G)$ on $D(A)$ is the graph norm defined by:

$$ \|u\|_G=\|u\|_X+\|Au\|_X,  \quad \forall u \in D(A)$$

$\bullet$ Not every linear operator is closable.

The question I want to address is: Show that there is no contradiction?

One may think that for every linear operator we can associate the graph norm to its domain and complete it to get a Banach space and by then a closed operator, the answer to this is that we can complete it to be a Banach space, but never to be a Graph of an operator, suppose for example that $A: D(A) \subset X \rightarrow X$ is a non-closable operator which means:

There exists sequence  $(x_n)_{x \geq 0}$ in $D(A)$ such that $x_n \rightarrow 0$ and $ Ax_n \rightarrow \alpha \in X$ such that $\alpha \neq 0$         $(*)$

The completion of $(D(A), \|\cdot \|_G)$ will never solve this issue but it will add limits of some sequences which didn't exist in $D(A)$

I find this question very educative and that this kind of question helps a lot to understand the topic whatever it is. My question is do you know any questions of this kind?  In Operator theory or any other topics in mathematic?
I would appreciate also it if you comment on my example above.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: The completion of $\Gamma(A)$ is a Banach space but it need not be the graph of an operator since you may have points of the form $(0,y)$, $y\neq0$ in it. You can indeed check that an operator is closeable iff there is no sequence $x_n\to 0$ so that $Ax_n$ converges to something not equal to $0$ - so this is the only problem here.

Comment: @s.harp Thanks for your comment, what one my check is that if the operator is closable, then its closure can be found by completing $(D(A),\|\cdot\|_G)$?